redis.rb - initialize': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError) #1277
trying to run websockets using action_cable sidekiq and redis (heroku redis addon).
on staging env that has same redis machine im able to run everything smoothly but on production upon trying to connect to websocket: wss://XXXXXX.herokuapp.com/cable i get the next error:
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:22:in initialize': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)`
full trace from heroku logs:
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158810+00:00 app[web.2]: #<Thread:0x0000563a510f8458 /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.7.7/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:150 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158858+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:22:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158888+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:22:in `initialize'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158889+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:254:in `new'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158890+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:254:in `connect'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158895+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:306:in `connect'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158896+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:385:in `establish_connection'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158900+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:115:in `block in connect'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158901+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:344:in `with_reconnect'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158910+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:114:in `connect'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158910+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:325:in `with_socket_timeout'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158921+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:174:in `call_loop'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158922+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:44:in `subscription'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158926+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:14:in `subscribe'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158927+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis.rb:288:in `_subscription'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158936+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/commands/pubsub.rb:20:in `block in subscribe'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158936+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis.rb:265:in `block in synchronize'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158937+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis.rb:265:in `synchronize'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158941+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis.rb:265:in `synchronize'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158942+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/commands/pubsub.rb:19:in `subscribe'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158953+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.7.7/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:83:in `block in listen'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158954+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:344:in `with_reconnect'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158955+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis.rb:95:in `block in with_reconnect'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158956+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis.rb:265:in `block in synchronize'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158965+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis.rb:265:in `synchronize'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158965+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis.rb:265:in `synchronize'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158969+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis.rb:94:in `with_reconnect'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158970+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis.rb:101:in `without_reconnect'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158980+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.7.7/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:80:in `listen'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.158980+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.7.7/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:154:in `block in ensure_listener_running'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188758+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:22:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188760+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:22:in `initialize'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188771+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:254:in `new'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188771+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:254:in `connect'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188772+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:306:in `connect'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188774+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:385:in `establish_connection'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188782+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:115:in `block in connect'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188782+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:344:in `with_reconnect'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188783+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:114:in `connect'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188793+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:325:in `with_socket_timeout'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188793+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:174:in `call_loop'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188801+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:44:in `subscription'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188801+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:14:in `subscribe'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188802+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis.rb:288:in `_subscription'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188820+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/commands/pubsub.rb:20:in `block in subscribe'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188820+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis.rb:265:in `block in synchronize'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188828+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis.rb:265:in `synchronize'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188828+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis.rb:265:in `synchronize'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188836+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/commands/pubsub.rb:19:in `subscribe'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188837+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.7.7/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:83:in `block in listen'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188838+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:344:in `with_reconnect'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188847+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis.rb:95:in `block in with_reconnect'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188847+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis.rb:265:in `block in synchronize'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188855+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis.rb:265:in `synchronize'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188855+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis.rb:265:in `synchronize'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188863+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis.rb:94:in `with_reconnect'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188863+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis.rb:101:in `without_reconnect'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188872+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.7.7/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:80:in `listen'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.188872+00:00 app[web.2]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.7.7/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:154:in `block in ensure_listener_running'
2024-05-12T13:48:46.268851+00:00 app[web.2]: [2] - Worker 0 (PID: 29) booted in 0.0s, phase: 0
2024-05-12T13:48:46.000000+00:00 app[redis-asymmetrical-47170]: Error accepting a client connection: (null)

#cable.rb:

development:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>

test:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV["REDIS_URL"] %>
  ssl_params:
    verify_mode: <%= OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE %>

staging:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV["REDIS_URL"] %>
  ssl_params:
    verify_mode: <%= OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE %>

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV["REDIS_URL"] %>
  channel_prefix: bw_backend_production
  ssl_params:
    verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE # For debugging SSL issues only

#sidekiq.rb 
# require 'logtail'
ssl_params = {
  verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
}

Rails.logger.info "Sidekiq SSL params: #{ssl_params.inspect}"
puts "Sidekiq SSL params: #{ssl_params.inspect}"

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  redis_options = { 
    url: ENV.fetch('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379/1'), 
    ssl_params: ssl_params 
  }
  Rails.logger.info "Sidekiq server Redis options: #{redis_options.inspect}"
  puts "Sidekiq server Redis options: #{redis_options.inspect}"
  config.redis = redis_options
  config.logger = Sidekiq::Logger.new($stdout)
  config.logger.level = Logger::INFO
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  redis_options = { 
    url: ENV.fetch('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379/1'), 
    ssl_params: ssl_params 
  }
  Rails.logger.info "Sidekiq client Redis options: #{redis_options.inspect}"
  config.redis = redis_options
end

#redis.rb
require 'uri'
require 'redis'

redis_uri = URI.parse(ENV['REDIS_URL'] || 'redis://localhost:6379/1')

redis_options = {
  host: redis_uri.host,
  port: redis_uri.port.to_i,  # Convert port to integer
  password: redis_uri.password,
  ssl: redis_uri.scheme == 'rediss',  # Enable SSL if scheme is 'rediss'
  ssl_params: {
    verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE  # Match ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE
  }
}

redis_options[:port] = redis_uri.port.to_i if redis_uri.port



# Initialize Redis client
Redis.new(redis_options)

configuration added:
config.action_cable.url = 'wss://XXXX.herokuapp.com/cable'
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'https://XXXX.herokuapp.com']
config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true`
Gemfile.lock related gems:
sidekiq (6.5.12)
connection_pool (\>= 2.2.5, \< 3)
rack (\~\> 2.0)
redis (\>= 4.5.0, \< 5)

tried different modifications on redis.rb , nothing changed the error

Protip - always use ENV.fetch(...) instead of ENV[...]. Getting a KeyError will save you so much debugging time compared to having a nil sneak it's way in. The exception is of course if the config var should be allowed to be nil.

Thanks !
iv'e changed in all places to use ENV.fetch(...) and still get same error

Hey! I couldn't find anything wrong with your setup on first sight but have you tried using a newer version of sidekiq and redis? Both version that you are using are over 2 years old and redis-rb code changed a lot since then.
